# Delete Ubuntu to free up space for computer restart properly

Tags: login-screen, delete

I copied photos onto my notebook hard drive and got a warning of limited hard drive space...I continued to copy photos onto my hard dirve. I got a message that the space limit was reached an no more photos could be copied onto the hard drive.
I restarted my notebook and the initial Ubuntu page could not load due to lack of memory. I tried to start-up in safe mode, buit to no avail. I guess that will mean that I uninstall Ubuntu completely and reinstall it again.
I have all important stuff backed up in case I need to unistall Ubuntu. My screen is black at the moment with my computer name prompting for the password. When I type in the password I get a message" the configuration defaults for GNOME Power Manager have not been installed correctly. See administrator."
I tried Crtl-Alt-F1 as suggested. I put in my laptop login and password...message now is: hylton@hylton:~$
Where do I go from here?

Comment: In the future, if a question gets closed due to lack of details you can edit that question and have it re-opened, instead of creating a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that is your home directory.i.e. /home/hylton Now. Do the stuff like clean up image with

```
cd Pictures/

ls

rm *.jpg
```

given your pictures are in the folder Pictures.

Or just copy your images from the location to some external storage device.

Answer (score 7):

There are several things you can do. There is no need to immediately jump into a reinstall. You can (now that you're in the command prompt) delete the various directories which are full of photos and other un-needed files. To do so you'll need to navigate to those directories and run the delete command.

This falls under the classification of "Basic Bash" but you'll mainly be using [cd](http://ss64.com/bash/cd.html), [ls](http://ss64.com/bash/ls.html), and [rm](http://ss64.com/bash/rm.html). For the example we'll assume you've placed the Photographic content in your "Pictures" directory.

```
cd ~/Pictures
ls
rm *.jpg
```

That will go into the Pictures directory, show a list of all the files, then it will delete all jpg files - the last part of the command will very depending on your file formats. If you wanted to delete all files in that directory just use an `*` if you wanted to delete all files and sub-folders you'll need to use `rm -r *` **Be very careful when using the `rm` command it's permanent**

If you are feeling a little more impatient you can just remove the entire Pictures directory like so:

```
cd ~
rm -rf Pictures
```

At any time you can check the diskspace you have available on your machine by typing `df -h` which will print out relevant diskspace information. Once you've cleaned space off you can run several other commands to help clear up diskspace:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

Which will clear your package cache and free up additional diskspace.

Issue a restart of your computer and everything should come back up. If not you'll likely have some corrupt configurations on your machine and need to reinstall packages.